# poetry add torch gives error: Unable to find installation candidates for nvidia-cudnn-cu11

Tags: torch, python-poetry

Running on mac m1 Monterey

Installing torch with poetry form a clean environment gives me the below runtime error:

```
✗ python --version    
Python 3.8.13

✗ poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.2.2)

✗ poetry add torch
Using version ^1.13.0 for torch

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.1s)

Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing nvidia-cublas-cu11 (11.10.3.66): Pending...
  • Installing nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11 (11.7.99): Failed

  RuntimeError

  • Installing nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11 (11.7.99): Failed

  RuntimeError

  • Installing nvidia-cublas-cu11 (11.10.3.66): Failed
  • Installing nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11 (11.7.99): Failed


  • Installing nvidia-cudnn-cu11 (8.5.0.96): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for nvidia-cudnn-cu11 (8.5.0.96)

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:103 in choose_for
       99│ 
      100│             links.append(link)
      101│ 
      102│         if not links:
    → 103│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
      104│ 
      105│         # Get the best link
      106│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
      107│
```

Installing with pip gives no issues:

```
✗ pip install torch        
Collecting torch
  Downloading torch-1.13.0-cp38-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (55.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 55.3/55.3 MB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /Users/vincent/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/recommend-drawify-iwMS_JJ1-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torch) (4.4.0)
Installing collected packages: torch
Successfully installed torch-1.13.0
```

I installed poetry using the official documentation: https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with no solution yet. You can track it here:

https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6939